# What standard is the word’s complexity in dictionary.com based on?

Tags: word-usage

I'm very surprised that the word [baa's complexity in dictionary.com is `College Level`](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/baa). But I had read this word in a children's book.

What standard is the word’s complexity in dictionary.com based on?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have no idea why they label it 'college level'. I consider representations of animal noises like _baa, meow_ and _moo_ to be 'nursery language' - the 'proper' terms being _bleat, mew_ and _low_.

Comment: This is probably a mistake.  The word is a "baby word" in the sense "the sheep say 'baa'" but is rare enough as a verb "the sheep baaed" to confuse whatever automatic system dictionary.com has of determining "complexity".  It seems also to be confusing the sheep sound with the acronym BAA

Comment: However, unless someone from the programming team at dictionary.com comes on to tell us about their algorithms, there is no way to answer this.  There is no official or standard way of identifying a word's complexity. So any answer would have to be based on opinion.  Good question, but unfortunately unanswerable.

Comment: This is probably the same data as their difficulty meter, which was removed from the site in late 2017. I wrote about it on [ELU meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11700/191178) but I never did find out where the information came from.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a specific feature of a specific dictionary, not about English.